# Validating data w/ Express before POST - Page hangs when data is invalid

Tags: node.js, express, post, express-validator

I'm using express-validator to find out if certain user inputs match specific keywords. If any of the inputs are invalid, a POST request to my db should not be made. If all of the inputs pass, then the POST should go through. The user should be re-directed to a `/submitted` view when the inputs are valid or invalid.

When none of the inputs are valid, the POST is *not* made and the db is not updated (which is good, since I don't want the db to have invalid data), **but the issue is that the page hangs and never reloads (has to be done manually).**

I have an if/else statement below that says what should be done if the data is invalid. The console says that `applicant.end()` and `res.end()` are not functions. Is there something else that I can write that'll "stop" the request but do the redirect?

```
app.post(
    "/application/submit",
    [
        check("_a1").matches("phrase-boundaries"), 
        check("_a2").matches("policy"),
        check("_a3").matches("src-authenticity"),
        check("_a4").matches("provide-phonics"),
    ], // each dropdown contains a value (i.e. ".a1" class has the value of "phrase-boundaries"), and those values need to match the text
    (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        const applicant = new Applicant(req.body);

        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            // if there are errors
            console.log("applicant provided wrong answer(s)");

            res.end() // The console says that applicant.end() and res.end() are not functions. Is there something else that I can write here that'll "stop" the request but do the redirect?
                .then((result) => {
                    res.redirect("/submitted");
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        } else {
            console.log("right answers");
        }

        applicant
            .save()
            .then((result) => {
                res.redirect("/submitted"); // this works when all of the checks pass
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the code like this:

```
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
     console.log("applicant provided wrong answer(s)");
     res.redirect("/submitted");
     return;
} else {
     console.log("right answers");
}

applicant
    .save()
    .then((result) => {
```

and the page is now behaving as expected. The redirect is performed and the `return` makes it so that `applicant.save()` does not happen.